# C# - how do I load different listviewitems when selecting different ComboBoxItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

```
private void cbKlik_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] izbira1 = { "Kingston 2, 5'' SSD disk 480 GB, SATA3", "DELL monitor LED UltraSharp U2412M", "Lenovo IdeaPad 110" };
    string[] izbira2 = { "PCX namizni računalnik Exam i5-7400/8GB/SSD120+1TB/Win10H", "Lenovo prenosnik V310", "Intel procesor Core i7-5820K" };
    string[] izbira3 = { "HP prenosnik Pavilion 17-ab004nm", "Intel procesor Core i7 6900K", "Gigabyte grafična kartica GTX 1080 OC" };
    string[] izbira4 = { "Asus prenosnik FX502VM-DM311T", "HP prenosnik Omen 17-w103nm", "DELL prenosnik Alienware 17" };

    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    int izbranIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;

    if (izbranIndex == 1)
    {
        lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
    }
    //lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();

}
```

I want to make it so that when I click one the first comboboxitem, the strings from the first array get added to the listview. But something is missing as there isn't anything happening. (Items.Clear is there just for the test, I will be also using it to clear previous listviewitems that I have defined in WPF). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to the `string[]`. Try to handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the ComboBox something like this:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] izbira1 = { "Kingston 2, 5'' SSD disk 480 GB, SATA3", "DELL monitor LED UltraSharp U2412M", "Lenovo IdeaPad 110" };
    string[] izbira2 = { "PCX namizni računalnik Exam i5-7400/8GB/SSD120+1TB/Win10H", "Lenovo prenosnik V310", "Intel procesor Core i7-5820K" };
    string[] izbira3 = { "HP prenosnik Pavilion 17-ab004nm", "Intel procesor Core i7 6900K", "Gigabyte grafična kartica GTX 1080 OC" };
    string[] izbira4 = { "Asus prenosnik FX502VM-DM311T", "HP prenosnik Omen 17-w103nm", "DELL prenosnik Alienware 17" };

    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    int izbranIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;

    switch (izbranIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira1;
            break;
        case 2:
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira2;
            break;
        case 3:
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira3;
            break;
        case 4:
            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira4;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but only in little cases unfortunately. I need to clear up the list before inserting new listviewitems, I do that with             lvDataBinding.Items.Clear(); which crashes my app after selecting a 2nd choice (probably because I clear an already empty list). How do I fix this?

Comment: You should clear the ListView by setting the ItemsSource property to null: lvDataBinding.ItemsSource  = null;

Comment: It works! Thanks! But I have another problem. The ListViewItems I had before (I made them in WPF) had onclick MessageBox that displays the name of the ListViewitem. Now that I load new ones with ComboBox and click on them, ofcourse it will display the name of the previous listviewitems. I need to define a data structure that keeps listview item names. How do I do that?

Comment: Please ask another question if you have another issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077945/c-sharp-how-do-i-implement-a-data-structure-that-contains-listviewitems

Comment: Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149768/c-sharp-how-to-add-images-from-folder-to-array-and-display-them-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment73382929_43149768

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SelectionChanged` event; then iterate through the array and add items to the listview.

```
if(izbranIndex == 1){
foreach (string item in izbira1){ 
   listview.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
cmb.SelectionChanged += cmbx_SelectionChanged;

void cmbx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Index has been changed {0}", yourcomobobox.SelectedIndex));
 if(yourcomobobox.SelectedIndex==1)
  {
   listview.Items.Clear();
   foreach (string item in izbira1){ 

   listview.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item));
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code for you. Hope it works. Mark it as answer if it helps you

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RNbUJF7X
This is how I used your solution if I understood right. But the problem is when I open MainWindow and click the first choice nothing happens. After clicking any other choice, items get added in the listview since I can click on them but no name is displayed. And the first choice is only functional when I don't click on it first.