# C# - how do I implement a data structure that contains ListViewItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So I'm doing a college project and my theme is web shop. What I have so far in C# is quite simple, I have a few ListViewItems (Articles) defined in WPF. Also when I change ComboBox index or click a button "New", other articles get inserted into my listview.

After that I needed to create an on click event that opens a new window with the listviewitem (article) details. I've hardcoded(if that's what it's called) this because I didn't know how to do it better.

The problem arises when I select a ComboBoxItem, which clears the listview and adds different items (articles) . When I click on the new articles, a window from the previous article opens when I click it.

I probably need to implement some kind of data structure that keeps ListViewItems, right? How would I approach doing this?

What I have so far:

```
namespace TRGOVINA
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void izhod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void btnNovosti(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] artikli = { "Intel procesor Core i7 6800K", "Intel procesor Core i5 7400", "AMD procesor Ryzen 7 1800X" };

            Artikel artikel1 = new Artikel();
            artikel1.Naziv = artikli[0];
            lvDataBinding.Items.Add(artikel1);

            Artikel artikel2 = new Artikel();
            artikel2.Naziv = artikli[1];
            lvDataBinding.Items.Add(artikel2);

            Artikel artikel3 = new Artikel();
            artikel3.Naziv = artikli[2];
            lvDataBinding.Items.Add(artikel3);
        }

        private void cbKlik_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] izbira1 = { "Kingston 2, 5'' SSD disk 480 GB, SATA3", "DELL monitor LED UltraSharp U2412M", "Lenovo IdeaPad 110" };
            string[] izbira2 = { "PCX namizni računalnik Exam i5-7400/8GB/SSD120+1TB/Win10H", "Lenovo prenosnik V310", "Intel procesor Core i7-5820K" };
            string[] izbira3 = { "HP prenosnik Pavilion 17-ab004nm", "Intel procesor Core i7 6900K", "Gigabyte grafična kartica GTX 1080 OC" };
            string[] izbira4 = { "Asus prenosnik FX502VM-DM311T", "HP prenosnik Omen 17-w103nm", "DELL prenosnik Alienware 17" };

            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            int izbranIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;

            //lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
            switch (izbranIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = null;
                    lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = null;
                    lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = null;
                    lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = null;
                    lvDataBinding.Items.Clear();
                    lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = izbira4;
                    break;
            }
          }

        private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //INSTEAD OF MESSAGEBOX A WINDOW HAS TO OPEN WITH LISTVIEW ITEM DETAILS - messagebox is just a placeholder
            int indeks = lvDataBinding.SelectedIndex;
            if (indeks == 0)
                MessageBox.Show(ime1.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (indeks == 1)
                MessageBox.Show(ime2.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (indeks == 2)
                MessageBox.Show(ime3.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (indeks == 3)
                MessageBox.Show(ime4.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (indeks == 4)
                MessageBox.Show(ime5.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (indeks == 5)
                MessageBox.Show(ime6.Text, "Naziv artikla", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }

        private void btnKosarica(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Kosarica kosarica = new Kosarica();
            kosarica.Show();
        }
    }

    public class Artikel
    {
        public string Naziv { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Naziv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hardly recommend getting familiar with the MVVM pattern when learning WPF. WPF without MVVM is ... just horrible.

Comment: I respect all recommendations but my instructions for the subject explicitly say I need to use a data structure (a class or something).

Comment: Yanketz, it is a bit stupid question but still, are you really doing a "web shop" with "desktop" WPF technology rather than something "web-specific" such as ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: MVVM is a design pattern and your Model would be the data structure. You would make things easier for yourself.

Comment: @SergGr Yes, I am using WPF to make a web shop. It's really not logical, but what can I do, the goal of the course is to learn how to make an interactive user interface, the themes were listed and we had to select one.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I know there's a better solution but it's really frustrating that nobody understands that we have to do it without it.

Comment: I guess nobody writes an answer because it's not really clear what you are doing or trying to do. At least for me.

Comment: Okay tell me what part you don't understand and I will try to explain it better.

Comment: It seems you think MVVM is something different than it actually is. MVVM is not a product or technology like WPF, WinForms, Java, etc. It is a design pattern. A design pattern is a way to utilize a technology. In fact, you could utilize MVVM in all the aforementioned products. You don't have to install MVVM, link it, download it from NuGet, or anything at all. MVVM is a way of laying out your code that makes WPF much easier to work with. So, when you say "we have to do without it", we're not sure what you mean. I'll be happy to answer your question when I better understand the requirements.

Comment: Oh okay but can you give me a simple example of MVVM?
  What I mean about "we have to do "without it" is that this is only the beginning and I doubt we "can" use these things. It can all be done with C# apparently.

My problem is: I click on a ListViewItem - a window with its description opens. I select a filter(comboboxitem) and the list gets cleared, different ListViewItems load. When I click on the first listviewitem in the NEW list - the window from BEFORE opens, because I've done it with indexes (ListView_MouseDoubleClick function).

How wouild I make this without indexes?

Comment: @JohnStrit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149768/c-sharp-how-to-add-images-from-folder-to-array-and-display-them-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment73382929_43149768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm goint to use MVVM in this answer since it's almost required for a WPF experience that doesn't include questioning your life choices. MVVM stands for Model, View, ViewModel. Something like this should get you started...

First is the Model. This is your data structure.

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then, your window in XAML. This is considered your view.

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_combobox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="_combobox" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemLists}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Last, this is what is called your ViewModel. This binds the View and Model together.

```
class ViewModel
{
    public List<List<Item>> ItemLists { get; private set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        string[] items = { "Intel procesor Core i7 6800K", "Intel procesor Core i5 7400", "AMD procesor Ryzen 7 1800X" };
        ItemLists = new List<List<Item>>();
        ItemLists.Add(new List<Item>());
        foreach (string item in items)
            ItemLists[0].Add(new Item(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the problem is that I also need the description of an Item alongside the name. And I use them in different textblocks and not always together. So adding it in the toString wouldn't do any good. Making another toString doesn't work either. Thoughts?

Comment: I believe that request belongs in the realm of a new question, but basically, just make a Description property in your Item class. Reference it from the TextBox like `<TextBox Text="{Binding Description}">`